# Button onclick="onclick()" throws Maximum stack error

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am playing with native JavaScript and stumbled upon something strange not sure why this is happening. I have plain html `button`. All I did is, set the `onclick="onclick()"`. When I run it and click on button I see that there's an error in console.

**Console:**

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I don't know why this error is coming. I am seeing this for the very first time. Even when I provide definition of `onclick` then also the error persists. Can anyone this why this is happening?

```js
console.log(window.onclick);//It logs null
```

```html
<button onclick="onclick()">Hit me
</button>
```

Comment: You bind the button's `onclick` with it's `onclick` function. When you click the button, `onclick` calls for itself again and again

Answer (score 0):

change `onclick` to something else

```
<button onclick="clickme()">Hit me
</button>
```

When you `click` button it will call your function `onclick` which will again call `onclick` event so it a never ending loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename onclick() function name. As Its calling itself every time.